# Automatically colorize the output of tree

Tags: zsh, colors, tree

In plain zsh, `tree` is set similar to `--color=auto` by default. However, when I use Oh-My-Zsh, `tree` doesn't show colors. Since `tree` does not have a `--color=auto` option, how can I override the setting back to the auto one?

Comment: Do you mean having no different colors by `--colors=auto`?

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar Well, `ls` works well with `--color=auto`, but `tree` does not have such an option. If it had, I could have just solved the problem with `alias tree='tree --color=auto'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer after I posted an [issue](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3951) on Oh-My-Zsh's repository. Color in tree rely on `LS_COLORS`, which is *not* set by Zsh by default; but my `~/.zshrc` set the variable after I hit "use default setting" option, with a single line

```
eval "$(dircolors -b)"
```

which looks insignificant. After installing Oh-My-Zsh, the setting is moved to `~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh`, so `LS_COLORS` is lost again, and my tree becomes black and white.

In other words, I moved that setting from `~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh` back to `.zshrc`, and I am now with my colorful tree.